# How can I test that a method is called on every element of an ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, relation

### Problem

I have a function that itterates through a Relation and calls a method on each member:

```
def do_stuff
  count = 0
  foo.bars.active.each do |bar|
    bar.stuff
    count += 1
  end
  count
end
```

Note: `active` is a scope on `bars` that returns a Relation instead of an Array.

My test looked something like this:

```
describe :do_stuff do
  let(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
  before    { foo.bars << FactoryGirl.create(:bar, :mock_stuff) }
  subject   { foo }
  it        { subject.do_stuff.should == 1 }
  it "does lots of stuff" do
    5.times { subject.bars << FactoryGirl.create(:bar, :mock_stuff) }
    subject.do_stuff.should == 6
  end
end
```

The Bar Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  data { random_string }

  trait :mock_stuff do
    after_build { |bar| bar.stub(:stuff).and_return(true) }
  end
end
```

The problem is I'm not actually verifying that `bar.stuff` ever gets called. I burned myself when I tried to refactor `do_stuff` to this:

```
def do_stuff
  foo.bars.active.count do |bar|
    bar.stuff
  end
end
```

All of the tests still pass even though calling `count` on an ActiveRecord::Relation won't execute the block :( I'd like to have a `before` block in my spec that does something like this:

```
before do
  foo.bars.each do |bar|
    bar.should_receive(:stuff)
  end
end
```

The problem is that the `bar` returned above will be a different instance than the one instantiated in the code.

### Answer

I finally figured it out. Here's the spec that fails when it should and doesn't make you worry about if you're iterating over an Array or a Relation:

```
describe :do_stuff do
  subject { FactoryGirl.create(:foo, :with_bar) }

  it "does stuff to bar" do
    Bar.any_instance.should_receive(:stuff)
    subject.do_stuff
  end
end
```

The trick here is that you **cannot** define foo in a `let` block like I did in the first example.

The Foo Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  data { random_string }

  trait :with_bar do
    after_build do |foo|
      foo.bars << FactoryGirl.create(:bar)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I do something dumb like `foo.bars.active.count do |bar|`, my spec fails and I know the code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
let(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
let(:bar) { double }
let(:array) { [bar] }

before do
  foo.stub(:bars).and_return(array)
end

it 'calls stuff on bar' do
  expect(bar).to receive(:stuff).once
  foo.do_stuff
end
```

You actually don't need to make sure it will be called `foo.bars.count` times, we can assume the ruby `count` method work properly. If it's called once, it will be called `n` times as well.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `bars` will return a relation and _not_ an array. So, by stubbing `bars` and returning `array` you've created a spec that will pass even though the code is broken. I know this because I did the same thing ;)

Comment: Just realized my question does not match the code I'm working on. There should be a scope on bars. Sorry for the confusion. I'll update the question.

Comment: it does not really maters, you can `stub_chain(:bars, :active)` to return an array. In the end, you end up with an iterator of elements.

Comment: Look at the refactored code example. Calling `count` on a Relation means that it will hit the database with `SELECT count * ...` and return an integer. The code inside the block will never be executed. Calling `count` on an Array will iterate over the elements so the block _will_ be executed. I really need something like `Bar.any_instance.should_receive(:stuff)` but it's not working on my setup.